# Stupidly simple calculus problem with unexpected answer...

Tags: calculus

Here is a simple calculus problem: The width of a rectangle is increasing at a rate of $\frac{1 \:cm} {min}$ and the height is decreasing at the rate $\frac{2 \:cm} {min}$. What is the rate of change of the area of a rectangle when it's width is $25cm$ and height is $15\:cm$
So, if $w$ is the width, $h$ is the height, $S$ is the area, the $\frac {dS}{dt}=dw\cdot h+dh \cdot w$= $1 \cdot 15+(-2) \cdot 25=15-50=-35$
The funny thing is that multiple choice for answers is as follows:

- a)-2
- b)-5
- c)-1
- d) 2

What am I doing wrong?...
Thanks for looking.

Comment: I obtained the same result by setting $h= 15-2t$ and $w=25+t$.

Comment: Or probably the problem says: the width decreases at a rate $2$cm/min and the height increases at a rate $1$cm/min. This will give the answer b).

Comment: Nope, the problem is exactly as I printed here... I've also noticed that if I switch h=25, w=15, I'd get -5, but I can't change condition of the problem just to get one of the "correct" answers...

Comment: They probably messed up the problem when they were writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trust your mathematics.

You have a function of the area in terms of time given by

$$S(t)=h(t)w(t)$$

then you differentiate and obtain

$$S'(t)=h'(t)w(t)+h(t)w'(t)$$

using the suggestion of Vladimir Vargas for $h=15−2t$ and $w=25+t$. You obtain $$S'(0)=-35$$  .

Comment: Many thanks to Vladimir Vargas and Yess!